# Retaining a radio button action after form validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an html form that has radio buttons (Eg: Yes/No). When I click 'Yes', some text boxes and other elements will become visible. When click 'No' those visible elements will hide. My issue is, lets say I click 'Yes' and a text box appears. But while form submission, validation failed. But the text box appeared earlier now disappeared although radio button remains 'Yes'. I need to toggle again to 'No' and then back to 'Yes' in order for the text box to appear again. Does anyone have idea how to solve it? My codes are as below. I am using php to submit form with some validation.

```js
$('#techYes').click(function() {
  if ($('#techYes').is(':checked')) {
    $(".tempPerm").show(); //Showing the whole hidden div
  }
});

$('#techNo').click(function() {
  if ($('#techNo').is(':checked')) {
    $("#revisionTechform").val(''); //Resetting techform Revision to NIL
    $("#techFormRemarks").val(''); //Resetting techform Remarks to NIL
    $("#temp").prop('checked', false); //Resetting Temporary Radio button
    $("#perm").prop('checked', false); //Resetting permanent Radion button
    $(".tempPerm").hide(); //Hiding the whole div
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Techform Updated?</label>
    <div class="form-check col-sm-6">
      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input " name="techformUpdated" id="techYes" value="techYes" <?php if (isset($_POST[ 'techformUpdated']) && $_POST[ 'techformUpdated']=="techYes" ) echo "checked";?>>
      <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>

      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="techformUpdated" id="techNo" <?php if (isset($_POST[ 'techformUpdated']) && $_POST[ 'techformUpdated']=="techNo" ) echo "checked";?> value="techNo">
      <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Edit

After many trials I am able to validate the form using jquery and now I am trying AJAX method to send the form data to a php file. But I am still having problem. Can someone help? My codes are as below. To understand the AJAX part, i edited the code slightly so that it won't confuse others.

```js
<script>
$("#submit").click(function() { 
    var prjId = $('#prjId').val();
    var flag = true;  
    if(flag) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "email_send.php",
            data: {prjId: prjId, updatedDate: updatedDate},
            success: function(response) {
            $('#result').html(response);

        });
    }
});

</script>
```

```html
<form method="post">       


        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Project ID</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                
              <?php
                if(isset($_POST['prjId'])){
                  echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Project ID" name="prjId" id="prjId" value="'.$_POST['prjId'].'">';  
                } else{
                  echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Project ID" name="prjId" id="prjId">';    
                }
                
              ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    
            <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Updated Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <?php
                if(isset($_POST['udatedDate'])){
                    echo '<input type="date" class="form-control" name = "updatedDate" value="'.$_POST['udatedDate'].'">';
                }else{
                  echo '<input type="date" class="form-control" name = "updatedDate">';  
                }
                
              ?>
              
            </div>
        </div>
    
    <div class="form-group row">
            <div class=" col-sm-3">
                <input type="submit" name ="btn-upload" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="saveBtnInitial">  
            </div>
        </div>
    
    <div id="result"></div>
    
</form>
```

The email_send.php page codes as below

```js
<?php
$prjId = $_POST['prjId'];
echo $prjId;
?>
```

Comment: Where is the form validation being done? In JS or PHP?

Comment: I am using php for form validation

Comment: Then when you resend the page, make the PHP send the new form in the correct state that fits what was on the form at the time it was submitted

Comment: Why dont you do js validation, before submit?

Comment: ok, so it's like a normal form submit by clicking radio button? Am I right? it clearly means page got refreshed? If yes then jQUERY created element will go.

Comment: Or make the page run a JS function when it reloads to set the correct state. Up to you which you pick

Comment: @RiggsFolly Could you give some sample code to understand? I don't know how to send the form in the correct state after a validation fail

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes. There is a submit button and once submitted and if there is a validation failure, page got refreshed and all the visible items will go hidden but 'Yes' button still remains 'Yes'

Comment: Why dont you have a go at which ever method you prefer, and if you cant get it working ask another question asking us to help you fix it

Comment: @Anu  you need to send form data via ajax to your PHP page and after checking return the final response to the same page again . then only you can do it correctly.Because once page refreshed, jQuery created element will gone

Comment: @AlivetoDie : Now I am trying AJAX as you suggested earlier (Please see the Edit). But i am not able to get the POST data. Do you know what am I doing wrong here?